# Photos skewing when dragged into Powerpoint

Tags: mac, ms-office, graphics

When I drop pics into Powerpoint they break into skewed parts, as shown below.  If I use the import function, it works just fine, but about 90% of the time when I copy/paste from anywhere, I get the skew.
This is something I do at least 30 times a day so it's killing productivity - would really like help if anyone has any idea.

[image]

Comment: In what format are the images? GIFs? JPEGs? PNGs?

Comment: In addition to @IconDaemon 's questions, what version of PowerPoint are you using? And what size are the images typically?